# Подделка данных в заголовке Origin (websocket)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Можно ли как-то подделать данные в заголовке Origin? 
Вопрос задан с целью защиты.

```
GET /ttt HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: http://webru.ru
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 32f2f2f2342r23
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете изменять `header` в `origin`, но вы можете модифицировать запросы для `header` через расширения, используя [**WebRequest**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Comment: То есть, подделать запрос можно и он будет валидным?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов да, будет валидным.

Comment: Получается нету способа проверить откуда пришло соединение? Хм...Странный протокол, везде пишут что защищенный.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Вы не меняете сам протокол, а меняете запросы

Comment: А что это значит? Что все в порядке и ничего подделать нельзя? Вы же только что написали можно подделать запросы. Или я вас не понял. Но в любом случае, Спасибо.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Это значит, что протокол останется прежним, но браузеры его будут воспринимать по-другому, в зависимости от запросов, которые вы напишете.

Comment: То есть, это надёжный протокол со стороны защиты, в котором можно подделать запросы и получить несанкционированный доступ к компьютерной информации? Получается так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46559/discussion-between-nikita-smith-and--).

Comment: Если можно, хотелось бы уточнения.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что мрожно перхватить запрос и переделать заголовок? или что7

Comment: так не получиться его подделать....

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно думать, можно ли подделать Origin, вместо этого Вы должны проверить, является ли Origin подходящим или нет, и вернуть нужный Access-Control-Allow-Origin. При правильном Access-Control-Allow-Origin кроссдоменная атака невозможна.